# Image In Line With Text HTML CSS

Tags: html, css, image, resize

Apologies still new to all this. I'm creating a webpage and have an image and text next to each other, in two separate div's. I've managed to get them where I want on the page, but when I resize the page the text resizes, however the image doesn't. I want the bottom of the text to line up with the bottom of the image at all times.

Any help appreciated! Here is code:

```
<head>

    <title>Stefano Mocini</title>
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Milonga' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <link href='styles/style.css' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
</head>

<body>

    <div id="title">
        Stefano Mocini
    </div>

    <div id="decal">
        <div id="image">
            <img src="images/tree.png" alt="tree" width="600" height="900">
        </div>      
    </div>

    <div id="about">
        <p>THANK YOU SO MUCH FOR YOUR REVIEWS; YOUR DONATION AND FOR SHARING MY MUSIC!!!</p>

        <p>About me: I started made music when I was only 6, because in the computer there was installed fruity loops, and I used it like a game. but i soon started to try to reproduce what i listened in the radio, so, step by step, i started to learn how to use this softwer. After i started to play the keyboard, that I received like christmast gift. One day I listened to "Back to life" from Allevi, and I loved it so much that I started to play the piano, every day. Step by step i learned how to make music, and how music is made . So now i can use the softwer whereby I played whan i was a child to make my own music. What kind of music should I make? Simply the one that I like!</p>

        <p>You can use my music for making non-commercial videos or projects, but please put the title of the song and the author in the description otf the video or in the  credits of the video.</p>

        <p>Commercial use of my music: by the PRO license, or contact me</p>
    </div>

</body>
```

```
body {
font-family: 'Milonga', cursive;
}

#title {
font-size:72pt;
text-align:center;
}


#decal {
float:left;
width:50%;
float:left;
height:80%;
}

#image {
margin-top:60%;
}

#about {
font-size:24pt;
float:left;
width:50%;
padding-top:5%;
height:80%;
}
```

Comment: Can you provide an online demo or create one at [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/?)

Comment: @farjam he's already posted his code, just make the fiddle yourself

Answer (score 7):

@Sourabh is close. But you'd be better off using `display:inline-block` instead of `float` and use `vertical-align:bottom` to align the bottoms.

CSS

```
* {
    font-family:'Milonga', cursive;
}
#title {
    font-size:72pt;
    text-align:center;
}
#decal {
    font-size:24pt;  /*Add this so that 1em is the same accross the divs*/
    padding-bottom:1em; /*Match the paragraph margin*/
    width:45%;
    display:inline-block;
    height:80%;
    vertical-align:bottom;
}
#image {
    margin-top:60%;
}

img {
    width: 100%
}

#about {
    font-size:24pt;
    display:inline-block;
    width:50%;
    padding-top:5%;
    height:80%;
    vertical-align:bottom;
}
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/ajdQa/

Comment: @Sourabh `inline-block` is now my go-to now instead of floats. If nothing else it means no clearfixes

Answer (score 1):

`user2458195` is right. But add width to CSS instead of using `width` attribute.

[**Check this**](http://jsfiddle.net/metacode/BaqTy/show/)

[**Full Screen**](http://jsfiddle.net/metacode/BaqTy/)

**CSS**

```
* {
    font-family:'Milonga', cursive;
}
#title {
    font-size:72pt;
    text-align:center;
}
#decal {
    width:45%; /* changed to get some space btween #decal and #about */
    float:left;
    height:80%;
}
#image {
    margin-top:60%;
}

img {
    width: 100% /* 100% of its parent ie, #decal*/
}

#about {
    font-size:24pt;
    float:right; /* right to get some space */
    width:50%;   /* try changing back to left n see what happens */
    padding-top:5%;
    height:80%;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that has made the image stop overlapping with the text which is awesome, but the image doesn't always remain inline with the bottom of the text when I resize the browser window, is there any way I can make this happen? I'm wondering if it's something to do with the padding-top for the image being a % ?

Answer (score 0):

please make img tag width=100% which will fit to decal div even on resize and add px to height

```
<div id="decal">
    <div id="image">
        <img src="images/tree.png" alt="tree" width="100%" height="900px">
    </div>      
</div>
```